# Array reshape error when loading word2vec model

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, gensim, word2vec

I have the following piece of code:

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
model = Word2Vec.load('model2')
X = model[model.wv.vocab]
```

This piece of code works on one of my machines but not another. The model file is the same. What's going on? The error message I get is the following:

```
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/word2vec.py", line 1330, in load
    model = super(Word2Vec, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 1244, in load
    model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 603, in load
    return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 427, in load
    obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 458, in _load_specials
    getattr(self, attrib)._load_specials(cfname, mmap, compress, subname)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 469, in _load_specials
    val = np.load(subname(fname, attrib), mmap_mode=mmap)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 440, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/miniconda3/envs/word2vec/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 771, in read_array
    array.shape = shape
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 16777184 into shape (134441,128)
```

To install gensim, I used `conda install -c anaconda gensim`

Comment: 16,777,184 elements is smaller – but only slightly – than the 17,208,448 that'd be required to fill a 134,441x128 array. Are you sure all the model's constituent files are identical in both places - not truncated in length in any way? (Can you list the files, with lengths, in both places for comparison?) Are there any other differences in OS, Python, or gensim version in the two different places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked what @gojomo referred to in the comments and he was correct, my file sizes were wrong. Something must have happened during upload. For large models, word2vec saves the model in 3 files. Assuming your model name is "model2" you will have:

1. model2
2. model2.trainables.syn1neg.npy
3. model2.wv.vectors.npy

My `.wv.vectors.npy` was a few kilo bytes too small than the version in my other machine.